# 500 Internal Server Error - Is there any method to debug and get more information

Tags: hosting, opencart, internal-server-error

Can someone tell me if  what are the best methods for debugging why a 500 error was thrown for my website.
I have OpenCart installed and suddenly stopped working. Now there is 500 internal server error and i can not access both admin and frontent. I have checked htaccess files and they are OK.

Also, along with all of the various opencart folders like admin or website root, there is created **core dump** files
They all start out core. with numbers attached like core.1024 with about 42MB file size.

I have contacted my Hosting provider and they said that the problem is with OpenCart code but I can not find any solution for this. Help please?